# How do I log the response time of the first packet?

Tags: apache

I'm very new to Apache. I need to log the response time of the first packet received.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

edit your apache configurations and try to include the following lines

```
# Define logfile format used for response time analysis
LogFormat "\"%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}t\" %V %m \"%U\" \"%q\" %{Content-Type}o %s %B %O %D" responsetime
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/responsetime.log" responsetime
```

for more information on logging mechanisms, kindly check

[Apache log file documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html)